# Redirect()->action() with parameter not working

Tags: laravel

Redirect Action Not Working

```
            return  redirect()->action(
                'AlumnoController@store', ['request' => NULL,'exception' => 1]
            );
```

Func Redirected  (AlumnoController@store)

```
    public function store(Request $request = NULL, $exception = 0)
    {
        return '<h1>'.$exception.'</h1>';

        if($exception){
            $alumno_id = $request->alumno_id;
            return view('alumno.create.salud', ['alumno_id' => $alumno_id]);
        }
    }
```

Result:
[Code result Wouldn't it be 1?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhfHI.png)

Can't find a way to fix it please help me.

Comment: The parameters passed to `action` are for the Route Parameters ... does your Route for this Action have parameters?

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that the action worked in a different way. My mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below:

1. redirect(route('store',$exception))->withInput();
2. redirect(route('store').'?exception='.@$exception);

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it as follows:

```
redirect()->route('store',[NULL, 1])->withInput();
```